# evaluating $\int\sqrt{81-x^2} \, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

So I know this problem needs trig sub to solve and I put it on the side opposite $\theta$ and I got a different answer since from the key since they put it on the length and not the height of the triangle.

I got a very similar answer, the only difference is that everything except C is - and instead of arcsin I had arccos.

Integral:

$$\int\sqrt{81-x^2} \, dx$$

Answer key:

$$\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{81-x^2}+\frac{81}{2}\arcsin\frac{x}{9}+C$$

My answer:

$$-\frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{81-x^2}-\frac{81}{2}\arccos\frac{x}{9}+C$$

To explain what I mean by opposite of $\theta$. In my triangle, $\cos\theta=\frac{x}{9}$. With the answer key's set up, $\cos\theta=\frac{\sqrt{81-x^2}}{9}$.

My question is how do you know where to put the radical on your triangle? It seems like it shouldn't matter since the triangle works.

Comment: $\arccos(x)  = \frac {\pi}{2}-\arcsin(x)$  Likely, your answer is perfectly good.

Comment: Is there a way I can use that to verify my answer? If I set the answers equal to each other I don't get anything meaningful.

Comment: You can always take the derivative of both functions and check if they are equal.

Comment: You can answer this question without calculus if you interpret this integral geometrically as the area under a circle and allow yourself basic geometric facts.

Comment: sure, substitute $(\frac {\pi}{2} - \arcsin (\frac x9))$ for $\arccos (\frac x9)$ in your answer and you should get the book answer.  And it looks like you dropped (or added) a minus sign somewhere along the way.

Comment: Oh you're right, I found the missing negative. Thank you.

Comment: @JairTaylor well it's indefinite haha

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima I upvoted but don't have enough rep so it didn't show :(. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @SakethMalyala You can find e.g. $\int_0^x \sqrt{1 - t^2}\, dt$

Comment: can you find that using basic geometry though? like if you were given the area represented by that integral? @JairTaylor seems unlikely

Comment: @SakethMalyala It is not too hard.  Try it!  Cut the region by the segment from the origin to $(x, \sqrt{1-x^2})$.  This gives a triangle and a sector of a circle.  Do you know how to find the area of a sector?

Comment: That is, $(x, \sqrt{81-x^2})$.

Comment: what the sh^t  IM MINDBLOWN. and the only tool you need is the calculator arcsine function for this geometric method, which you'd also need for the indefinite integral. amazing. thank you. i have been enlightened @JairTaylor

Comment: @SakethMalyala no problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int \sqrt {81-x^2}\ dx$ don't forget the index of integration.

Either one of these substitutions is acceptable.

$x = 9\cos t$ or $x = 9\sin t$

Lets demonstrate both ways

$\int \sqrt {81-x^2}\ dx\\
x = 9\cos t\\
dx = -9\sin t\\
\int \sqrt {81-81\cos^2 t}(-9\sin t)\ dt\\
\int - 81 \sin^2 t dt\\
\int - \frac {81}{2} + \frac {81}2\cos 2t\ dt\\
 - \frac {81}{2}t + \frac {81}4\sin 2t\\
- \frac {81}{2}t + \frac {81}2 \sin t\cos t+C\\
t = \arccos \frac {x}{9}\\
- \frac {81}{2}\arccos \frac {x}{9} + \frac {81}2 (\sqrt {1-\frac {x^2}{81}})( \frac {x}{9})+C\\
- \frac {81}{2}\arccos \frac {x}{9} + \frac 12 x\sqrt {81-x^2}  + C 
$

$\int \sqrt {81-x^2}\ dx\\
x = 9\sin t\\
dx = 9\cos t\\
\int \sqrt {81-81\sin^2 t}(9\cos t)\ dt\\
\int 81 \cos^2 t dt\\
\int \frac {81}{2} + \frac {81}2\cos 2t\ dt\\
  \frac {81}{2}t + \frac {81}4\sin 2t\\
\frac {81}{2}t + \frac {81}2 \sin t\cos t+C\\
t = \arcsin \frac {x}{9}\\
\frac {81}{2}\arcsin \frac {x}{9} + \frac {81}2 \frac {x}{9}\sqrt {1-\frac {x^2}{81}} +C\\
\frac {81}{2}\arcsin \frac {x}{9} + \frac 12 x\sqrt {81-x^2} + C 
$

Both are fine ways to go.

$- \frac {81}{2}\arccos \frac {x}{9} + \frac 12 x\sqrt {81-x^2}  + C = \frac {81}{2}\arcsin \frac {x}{9} + \frac 12 x\sqrt {81-x^2} + D$

as 
$ -\frac {81}{2}\arccos \frac {x}{9}$ differs from $\frac {81}{2}\arcsin \frac {x}{9}$ by a constant.

Generally, you will see the $x = a \sin t$ substitution because it has fewer minus signs.

Comment: I love to see it been done with both subsitutions and I love the explanation at the end. That way, you take the "magic" out of the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

Put $$x=9\cos (t) $$
with $t\in [0,\pi] $.

the integral becomes

$$-81\int \sqrt {1-\cos^2 (t)}\sin (t)dt $$

$$-81\int \frac {1-\cos (2t)}{2}dt $$

You can finish using
$$\sin (2t)=2\sin (t)\cos (t) $$
$$=2x/9.\sqrt {1-x^2/81} $$

Answer (score 0):

ArcSin and and ArcCos add up to $ \pi/2 $ or $ 3 \pi/2$. In the presence of an arbitrary constant one integral result can be expressed/absorbed in terms of the other.